# Run cwebp.exe in my batch file not working with space in file name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I create batch file in windows and add it in context menu to run script with right click menu.

Batch file looks like:

```all-bat
@echo off

cwebp.exe -q 100 -m 6 -mt -af -progress -short %1 -o %~n1.webp
```

Script working fine if filename have no spaces in it.
e.g: `LogoBlack.png`

The problem is, script not working if file name have spaces.
e.g: `Logo Black.png`

The `cwebp.exe` error returns this message:

> ```all-bat
> Converting file D:\Kashif\images\AMG Logo Black.png
> SHCreateStreamOnFile((const LPTSTR)filename, > STGM_READ, stream) failed 80070002
> Error opening input file Black.webp (80070002)
> OpenInputStream(filename, &stream) failed 80070002
> cannot open input file 'Black.webp'
> Error! Could not process file Black.webp
> Error! Cannot read input picture file 'Black.webp'
> ```

Comment: Test "%1", or pass in the filename *already quoted*, e.g. **"Logo Black.pnd"**.

Comment: I did as you said, but no luck

Comment: Putting quotes around the output path doesn't help,  like `-o "%~n1.webp"`? (BTW, given that this question is based off the output of an old answer, https://superuser.com/a/1531865/368970 it would be good if you mention that in your question.)

Comment: If possible, please... edit the question and put the registry entry for right click menu,

Comment: I used Easy Context Menu [link](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/) to add right click menu

Comment: if one not interested in scripting and manual work, then use **File Converter v1.2.3** [link](https://file-converter.org/) I found this software very useful, it convert multiple extensions including webp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```all-bat
@echo off

set "_cwebp=%UserProfile%\Downloads\libwebp-1.2.0-windows-x64\bin\cwebp.exe"
          
timeout 5 | 2>&1 "%_cwebp%" -q 100 -m 6 -mt -af -progress -short "%~f1" -o "%~dpn1.webp"
```

[`cwebp.exe` Ver/Link](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.2.0-windows-x64.zip)

---

**Obs.:** A ***`Timeout 5`*** it is there to facilitate drag and drop actions and to allow reading some error return if it occurs, in addition to the execution

---

```all-bat
@echo off

set "_cwebp=%UserProfile%\Downloads\libwebp-1.2.0-windows-x64\bin\cwebp.exe"

timeout 5 | 2>&1 "%ComSpec%" /v:off /e:off /s /c ^"call "%_cwebp%" -q 100 -m 6 -mt -af -progress -short "%~fs1" -o "%~dpn1.webp"^"
```

Comment: with "%~fn" and "%~dpn1" it works like charm. thanks, in continuation if any file have special character in its name then file, `I know using special characters in file name is not a good idea but if one have`  conversion complete but with filename not found error or something else. required your help in this too

Comment: Plz, try the second code and let me know the characters that cause you problems for a more specific attention, thank you for testing, commenting and other pertinent actions.

Comment: its working, and `&` was making problem